# form submit with angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

hey for some reason I cannot submit my form can anyone explain why?
I'm using Angular Material.

html:

```
<mat-dialog-content>

<form class="example-form"[formGroup]="movieForm" (ngSubmit)="addMovie(movieForm.value)">

    ......


<button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="!movieForm.valid" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Save</button>
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Cancel</button>
</form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

and this is the component:

```
addMovie(form) {
    console.log("check");
  }
```

How come I cant see the console.log?

Comment: console.log(form); ???

Comment: But since it is on component side anyway, why do you need to pass it as argument?

Comment: to get the values from the form?

Comment: May be your form is not valid so form is not submit

Comment: it is valid cause i have a button disabled until the form is valid, and only then you can press it

Comment: Your `<form>` might be invalid - i mean html form element, not angular backing form group - eg. you didnt bound some input to backing formGroup thus it is valid, but html form as overall is invalid .

Comment: its working if it delete this line:  [mat-dialog-close]="true", but then how can i close the dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't  need to pass any parameter because you already have the `movieForm` references in you **component.ts**  .just do the following:

**Template html**

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="addMovie()">
```

**Component.ts**

```
  addMovie() {
    console.log(this.movieForm);
  }
```

To access directly to your values check the console object result *structure*. You will see all the properties that you can access.

Comment: thanks for this comment but i did it in purpose to avoid from large code since Im using this values to create new movie object. anyway i fixed my problem thanks :)